# Two docker services depends_on the same service

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, orchestration

I am having two docker-compose files

/cfacing/docker-compose.yml

```
  app-customer-facing:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - mysql-db

  mysql-db:
    container_name: staging-mysql-db
    image: mysql:5.6
```

/afacing/docker-compose.yml

```
  app-admin-facing:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - mysql-db

  mysql-db:
    container_name: staging-mysql-db
    image: mysql:5.6
```

I want both customer-facing container and admin-facing container to depend on the same mysql-db container. This is currently not working, the `app-customer-facing` will start with mysql-db but app-admin-facing will not start throwing:

`ERROR: for mysql-db  Cannot create container for service mysql-db: Conflict. The container name "/staging-mysql-db" is already in use by container "fe63e1ab0c1fd19236551bfc5930544cb31e649a4c18421c05959dc1274eb600". You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.`

Answer (score 0):

The error is that you are duplicating your **mysql-db** service, you are not re-using it. That's why you get an error telling that there is already a container named **staging-mysql-db**.

To resolve your use case, you'll have to extend your docker-compose file.
You can see an exemple [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/). See the block **ADMINISTRATIVE TASKS** which is basically what you are trying to do.

Comment: This is not just about naming there are also networking issues that the docker-compose files are trying to solve

Comment: By overriding one compose file, all the container will be on the same network. You won't have any network issue.

Comment: These are different git repos... moreover, the docker is in the swarm mode

Comment: What do you mean by "the docker is in swarm mode" ? Are you deploying a swarm stack ?   
If that's the case then the **depends_on** option is ignored by swarm. See the [reference documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#depends_on)